# How to make 3rd party request from a React Native WebView which has loaded a local HTML file and avoid CORS

Tags: react-native, webview, request, cors, local-files

I have created a React Native app which uses a WebView. In the WebView I have managed to load a local HTML file, local CSS files and local JS files. So far so good.

The problem I am facing is this: My Javascript functions need to perform `fetch()` requests (GET and POST) to 3rd party endpoints. I get CORS errors because, because the WebView's origin is `http://192.168.1.4:8081` and as you would guess this origin isn't registered into my server's CORS allow list.

My research so far is unfruitful. Is anyone aware of a way where I can specify the origin of the `fetch()` requests? In fact I need something similar to the `html` and `baseURL` combination, but I want the baseURL to apply *only* to the `fetch()` requests.

Thank you

Comment: If it was possible to manipulate the Origin of a browser request, that would make the CORS protocol useless.